# Plotting GPS data onto a roadmap in Matlab

Tags: matlab, google-maps, plot, gps, openstreetmap

I have latitude, longitude, and speed data. I want to plot this onto a roadmap and get a 3D plot. The roadmap can be just like google maps. I looked into openstreetmap, and they are pretty too. I want to get this plot in a figure.

Also after seeing `meshc`, and `surfc`, it would be much better to have the road map on the lower surface and have other data above. It will look like the projection of a trip on the map.

I have found function in the [link here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27627-zoharby-plot-google-map) which uses google maps to plot on a figure. By using this and using `plot3` command in matlab I was able to plot the speed. However the figure is 2D and looking from top. Whenever I use `3D rotate` and rotate the figure to see the speed, the google map disappears.

For those of you who want to help me with this issue I include a sample data in matlab .mat format. Columns are: `[lon lat speed]`.It can be downloaded at [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s3xaeu195rp7xlj/X_roadmapdata.mat?dl=0).

Also, if any of you can point a way to save at least some portion (a region) of a roadmap database so that we can call the map directly from there that would be very good. But if that is not possible and these maps can only be fetched online that's fine too.

Below is my code of what I did with the above toolbox. I just followed the sample in the link and added the speed as a third dimension.

Thank you in advance!

```
load X.mat
lonlat = [];
lonlat(:,1) = X(:, 1);
lonlat(:,2) = X(:, 2);
speed = X(:, 3);

figure
plot(lonlat(:, 1), lonlat(:, 2), 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
% Put a begin and end marker
line(lonlat(1, 1), lonlat(1, 2), 'Marker', 'o', ...
    'Color', 'b', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'MarkerSize', 10);
line(lonlat(end, 1), lonlat(end, 2), 'Marker', 's', ...
     'Color', 'b', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'MarkerSize', 10);
hold on
plot3(lonlat(:,1),lonlat(:,2), speed);
plot_google_map('maptype', 'roadmap');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of plot_google_map. I tried playing around with my function to support the 3d case. You can replace the following line:

```
h = image(lonVect,latVect,uniImag, 'Parent', axHandle);
```

with:

```
h = surf(lonVect,latVect,zeros(length(latVect), length(lonVect)),  uniImag, 'EdgeColor',  'none', 'FaceLighting', 'flat', 'EdgeLighting', 'none', 'Parent', axHandle);
```

This theoretically does what you want, but results in a very slow responding figure, which I'm not sure is really usable, since 3D navigation in MATLAB figures is very unnatural.

If you think this mode is usable, let me know and I'll add it to the main code.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your help. Yes indeed it becomes very slow. And it also becomes distorted. Is there a way to draw the speed in the bottom part instead of top? The whole project is an awesome job by the way, I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: I think your best approach would be to use color coding for the speed with scatter or simiar. For a colored line, try this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19476-colored-line-or-scatter-plot